# How to make a good plot for this scenario

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, dplyr

I have this code:

```
new_flts.df %>%
  mutate(DELAY_CAT = fct_collapse(DELAY_CAT,
          OnTime = c("On Time", "Short Delay"),
          Delayed = c("Medium Delay", "Long Delay", "Very Long Delay"),
          Canceled =("CNL")
          ))%>%
  filter(DIR=="D") %>%
  group_by(AIRL, ORGDEST, DELAY_CAT)%>%
  tally()%>%mutate(perc = percent(n/sum(n),accuracy = 1))
```

It produces the following output (part of output):

```
# A tibble: 260 x 5
# Groups:   AIRL, ORGDEST [94]
    AIRL  ORGDEST DELAY_CAT     n perc 
    <fct> <fct>   <fct>     <int> <chr>
  1 ADR   DUS     OnTime       43 49%  
  2 ADR   DUS     Delayed      31 36%  
  3 ADR   DUS     Canceled     13 15%  
  4 ADR   FRA     OnTime     1673 86%  
  5 ADR   FRA     Delayed     237 12%  
  6 ADR   FRA     Canceled     26 1%   
 24 ART   DUS     OnTime       39 57%  
 25 ART   DUS     Delayed      26 38%  
 26 ART   DUS     Canceled      4 6%   
 27 ART   MLH     OnTime       77 53%  
 28 ART   MLH     Delayed      52 36%  
 29 ART   MLH     Canceled     17 12%  
 30 ART   MUC     OnTime       22 61%  
 31 ART   MUC     Delayed      11 31%  
 32 ART   MUC     Canceled      3 8%   
 44 BUR   DUS     OnTime       53 50%  
 45 BUR   DUS     Delayed      45 43%  
 46 BUR   DUS     Canceled      7 7%   
 47 BUR   HAJ     OnTime       17 45%  
 48 BUR   HAJ     Delayed      20 53%  
 49 BUR   HAJ     Canceled      1 3%   
 50 BUR   MLH     OnTime      158 57%  
 51 BUR   MLH     Delayed     101 37%  
 52 BUR   MLH     Canceled     16 6%   
 53 BUR   OTP     OnTime       30 45%  
 54 BUR   OTP     Delayed      30 45%  
 55 BUR   OTP     Canceled      6 9%
```

After plotting the best I got was this (picture below). But I am not happy with it. I want to show a good plot with performance percentages for each AIRLINE and DESTINATION. Any help for making a good information plot!

plot code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(AIRL, perc))+
  geom_col(aes(fill=DELAY_CAT))+facet_wrap(.~ORGDEST, scales = "free")
```

[image: Plot image]

Comment: Some destinations have one airline and others have many. Such "many-to-many" relationships are a pain to illustrate. For now, you only told us that you're not happy with your plot although it displays percentages for each airline and destination as you wanted. You have a close vote already, and I guess that the reason why is that you are not asking a question. Please take a look at other questions on StackOverflow so you can see how it is constructed and edit your own, otherwise chances are unfortunately high that this question will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

My intuition is that you would benefit from getting all the information on one plot and not use `facet_wrap` in this case? You could combine the two variables you are interested in using `paste`. See this example.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- mtcars

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(CylVs = paste(cyl,vs))

ggplot(df,aes(x = carb,fill = CylVs)) + 
  geom_histogram()
```

Good luck!